# force container outbound traffic via another container (without host iptables rules)

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I have two containers, `A` & `B`.

They should exist on a newly created docker (private) bridge network such that:

- `A` can talk to the world outside the bridge, but only via specified gateway IP
- `B` cannot talk outside the bridge, only to `A` via specific ip+port
- **Prefer not to require use of iptables rules** on *host*.
- Prefer not to require `--privileged` on either `A` or `B`, but specific `--device` might be OK
- I'm OK with using `--cap-drop` on B to achieve desired isolation

I've played around a bit with `docker network create bridge private-bridge` and various combinations of `docker run -net=private-bridge` but can't get the behavior I'm looking for.

Is there some way to:

- do this with a docker `bridge` network?, or
- do this with a different standard network type?, or
- should I look into writing a custom docker network plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like *some* kind of SDN was required, but https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework was a lot simpler to get going than others like Contiv, etc.

No extra container privileges were required, and the containers (even as root) couldn't manipulate the bridge nor their own interfaces with the default docker container privileges.

Firstly, install `pipework` & `brctl`

```
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpetazzo/pipework/master/pipework \
          > /usr/local/bin/pipework
sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/pipework
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

Before we start, check the interfaces and bridges currently defined:

```
brctl show | tail -n+2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo 
# docker0

ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# eth0 docker0 lo
```

For this demo, I'll create an image called `net-tester` with basic network testing functionality included:

```
docker run -itd --name=jtest debian:jessie
docker exec -it jtest apt-get update
docker exec -it jtest apt-get install -y traceroute curl dnsutils \
                                         netcat-openbsd jq nmap \
                                         net-tools isc-dhcp-client telnet
docker exec -it jtest apt-get clean
docker commit -p jtest net-tester
docker stop jtest && docker rm jtest
```

Start the two containers on the standard docker `none` network:

```
docker run -itd --net=none --name=node-a net-tester
docker run -itd --net=none --name=node-b net-tester

docker exec -it node-a ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# lo

docker exec -it node-b ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# lo
```

Create `br0` bridge and, and add interfaces on `br0` to `node-a` and `node-b`.

```
sudo pipework br0 node-a 192.168.10.1/24
sudo pipework br0 node-b 192.168.10.2/24

docker exec -it node-a ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# eth1 lo

docker exec -it node-b ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# eth1 lo
```

(Implicitly named) interface `eth1` was created on both containers.

Let's look at the host bridges and interfaces now:

```
brctl show | tail -n+2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# br0 veth1pl31667 docker0

ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# br0 docker0 eth0 lo veth1pl31645 veth1pl31667
```

Let's look at the routing on those containers:

```
docker exec -it node-a route -n
# Kernel IP routing table
# Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
# 192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

docker exec -it node-b route -n
# Kernel IP routing table
# Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
# 192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Finally we add `eth0` interface to `node-b` on host's subnet.

In my case: eth0 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.0.0.1.

```
sudo pipework eth0 -i eth0 node-b 10.0.0.99/24@10.0.0.1
```

Apparently this can also be done with dhcp.

Now, checking for interfaces on `node-b` gives:

```
docker exec -it node-b ifconfig | grep encap | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs echo
# eth0 eth1 lo
```

Routing looks like this:

```
docker exec -it node-b route -n
# Kernel IP routing table
# Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
# 0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
# 10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
# 192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Test connectivity of `node-a`:

```
docker exec -it node-a ping -c 3 192.168.10.2
# PING 192.168.10.2 (192.168.10.2): 56 data bytes
# 64 bytes from 192.168.10.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
# 64 bytes from 192.168.10.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
# 64 bytes from 192.168.10.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
# --- 192.168.10.2 ping statistics ---
# 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
# round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.092/0.106/0.124/0.000 ms

docker exec -it node-a ping -c 3 10.0.0.1
# PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
# ping: sending packet: Network is unreachable

docker exec -it node-a ping -c 3 8.8.8.8
# PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
# ping: sending packet: Network is unreachable
```

Test connectivity of `node-b`:

```
docker exec -it node-b ping -c 3 192.168.10.1
# PING 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1): 56 data bytes
# 64 bytes from 192.168.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
# 64 bytes from 192.168.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
# 64 bytes from 192.168.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
# --- 192.168.10.1 ping statistics ---
# 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
# round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.086/0.092/0.102/0.000 ms

docker exec -it node-b ping -c 3 10.0.0.1
# PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
# 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.312 ms
# 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.314 ms
# 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.289 ms
# --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
# 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
# round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.289/0.305/0.314/0.000 ms

docker exec -it node-b ping -c 3 8.8.8.8
# PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
# 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=19.309 ms
# 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=18.279 ms
# 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=19.827 ms
# --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
# 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
# round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 18.279/19.138/19.827/0.643 ms
```

Curiously, while `node-b` can ping other IPs on the host's ethernet subnet, it can't ping hosts's `eth0` IP itself. That's actually what I wanted so I'm not bothered.

When both containers have been stopped, we can clean up the bridge:

```
sudo ifconfig br0 down
sudo brctl delbr br0
```

For my specific scenario, if I bind some daemon to `0.0.0.0` on `node-b` that will be visible to all on the host ethernet (via `10.0.0.99`), so I had to be careful to bind specifically to `192.168.10.2`.